Proving the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality using Discriminants
As a learning exercise, I am trying to prove the Cauchy-Schwarz (in the context of probability).
The Cauchy-Schwarz inequality states that for random variables X and Y:
$$(E[XY])^2 \leq E[X^2] \cdot E[Y^2]$$
The way I see it, the left hand side can be represented by a quadratic function of a real variable t:
$$f(t) = E[(X + tY)^2]$$
Expanding:
$$f(t) = E[X^2 + 2tXY + t^2Y^2]$$
Take the expected value:
$$f(t) = E[X^2] + 2tE[XY] + t^2E[Y^2]$$
Now we take the discriminant.
In general, for a quadratic function
$$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$$
The discriminant is:
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$$
Since the above function is a quadratic function in $t$ and expectations of squared random variables are non-negative, $f(t)$ must be non-negative for all real t. This means that the discriminant of this quadratic must be less than or equal to zero:
$$\text{discriminant} = (2E[XY])^2 - 4E[X^2]E[Y^2] \leq 0$$
Simplify:
$$4(E[XY])^2 - 4E[X^2]E[Y^2] \leq 0$$
Divide by 4:
$$(E[XY])^2 - E[X^2]E[Y^2] \leq 0$$
Rearrange:
$$(E[XY])^2 \leq E[X^2]E[Y^2]$$
And this is the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality!
Did I prove this correctly?


Note 1: My main takeaway is that $f(t) = E[(X + tY)^2] \geq 0$ for all real t. This is because the expectation of a squared quantity is always non-negative.

We showed that
$$f(t) = E[Y^2]t^2 + 2E[XY]t + E[X^2]$$
I.e. $a = E[Y^2]$, $b = 2E[XY]$, and $c = E[X^2]$.
For a quadratic function to be non-negative for all real t, it must either:

Have no real roots (parabola always above the t-axis), or
Have exactly one real root (parabola touches the t-axis at exactly one point)

Mathematically, these conditions are equivalent to saying that the discriminant must be less than or equal to zero:
$$b^2 - 4ac \leq 0$$
If the discriminant were positive, the quadratic would have two real roots, meaning there would be values of t for which $f(t) < 0$, which contradicts the fact that $f(t) \geq 0$ for all t.
Substituting the values for a, b, and c:
$$(2E[XY])^2 - 4E[Y^2]E[X^2] \leq 0$$


Note 2:
A review of intro calculus:

Proving that the vertex is at $x = -b/(2a)$
To find the vertex, we need to find the x-coordinate where the parabola reaches its maximum or minimum. This occurs where the derivative of the function is zero.
Derivative of $f(x)$:
$$f'(x) = 2ax + b$$
Set the derivative to zero and solve for x:
$$\begin{align}
   2ax + b &= 0 \\
   2ax &= -b \\
   x &= -\frac{b}{2a}
   \end{align}$$
Thus, the x-coordinate of the vertex is $$x = -b/(2a)$$.
Why $f(-b/(2a)) = -\Delta/(4a)$
Here is how we can show that the x-coordinate of the vertex into our quadratic function, we get $-\Delta/(4a)$, where $\Delta$ is the discriminant ($\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$).
Start with our quadratic function and substitute $x = -b/(2a)$:
$$\begin{align}
   f\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) &= a\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 + b\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) + c
   \end{align}$$
Simplify
$$\begin{align}
   a\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2 &= a \cdot \frac{b^2}{4a^2} = \frac{b^2}{4a} \\
   b\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) &= -\frac{b^2}{2a} \\
   c &= c
   \end{align}$$
Add these terms:
$$\begin{align}
   f\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) &= \frac{b^2}{4a} - \frac{b^2}{2a} + c \\
   &= \frac{b^2}{4a} - \frac{2b^2}{4a} + \frac{4ac}{4a} \\
   &= \frac{b^2 - 2b^2 + 4ac}{4a} \\
   &= \frac{-b^2 + 4ac}{4a} \\
   &= -\frac{b^2 - 4ac}{4a}
   \end{align}$$
We are saying that $b^2 - 4ac$ is the discriminant $\Delta$, thus:
$$f\left(-\frac{b}{2a}\right) = -\frac{\Delta}{4a}$$
Properties of the discriminant:
For the equation of the discriminant  $\Delta$:
$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$
$$\Delta = b^2 - 4ac$$

Case 1: When the discriminant is positive, we have two solutions: $x_1 = \frac{-b + \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ and $x_2 = \frac{-b - \sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}$ (i.e. two intersections with the x-axis, parabola can be negative technically)
Case 2: When the discriminant is 0, we have one repeated solution: $x = \frac{-b \pm 0}{2a} = \frac{-b}{2a}$ (i.e. one intersection with the x-axis, parabola can be negative technically)
Case 3: When the discriminant is negative, we have no intersection with the x-axis (i.e. parabola only has positive values)

Case 3 corresponds to the Expectation from the Cauchy-Schwarz proof. A squared function of expected values can only be positive, implying that the discriminant must be negative or less. This is why we have a less than equal sign.

yes you are correct

thank you Andrew!
